# aem - create new author dialog tab - on click

Tags: dynamic, tabs, onclick, aem

I am using AEM 6.1- classic, and working on a nested multifield implementation. As its getting too complicated, I am thinking of splitting parts of it into tabs.

So first tab, I add some data, then on click of 'add new' button, I want to be able to create a new tab, so that I can now go into the new tab and add the new data there. and so on.

Has anyone come across such implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with similar issue when on change specific field some fields should be hidden and some ones should be shown. So the implementation was to add the handler to dialog's event and we get needed result. So, back to your question, I guess that you can add event listener to your button and handle this event using js to show one more tab you need. If this way suits you I can made in hurry some implementation as soon as I can.